# Rounding a number up

Tags: javascript

I want to round the up my total til two decimal places.

I have this:

```
    var updateTotal = function () {
      var people = parseInt($('#people').val());
      var bill = parseInt($('#bill').val());
      var tip = parseInt($('#tip').val());
      var billTip = bill + tip;




      $('#total').text(billTip / people);
```

and i've also found this snippet to help round up but i cant seem to get my head around how to implement it.

```
    var rounded = Math.round((10 / 3) * 100) / 100;
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the problem, exactly?

Comment: @pattyd The accepted answer there isn't jQuery either.

Comment: @pattyd OP tag it using jquery but of course this is non sense here to tag it with jquery

Comment: @Jack ... my bad... didn't noticed the code was Jquery, I guess I just noticed the Tag... Sorry!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's already implemented for you. Substitue (10 / 3) for your own variables. All it's doing is shifting the decimal place two places to the right (by multiplying by 100), rounding, then shifting it two left (by dividing by 100).

```
var rounded = Math.round((billTip / people) * 100) / 100;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `.toFixed`

```
$('#total').text((billTip / people).toFixed(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `parseFloat` on both your numbers, or else it will round to `00`:

```
$('#total').text(parseFloat(billTip / people).toFixed(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ceil function `Math.ceil(billTip)`

and for refernce you can also visit below link

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_ceil.asp